# RWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration error in final iOS 11 with Xcode 9 gmseed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios11

I have an Xcode build error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libXRPlugin.a(ios-arkit-sensor.o)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, and learn about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]). You need to provide a lot more context before we're able to help you solve your problem. I've retagged the question with more relevant tags (I'm not sure that [tag:ar] belongs at all, but I've left it in deference to your original thoughts).  The programming language and platform tags are much more important than a 'minority interest' tag like [tag:ar].  I only spotted the question because I was looking for questions abusing the tag when they mean [tag:augmented-reality].

Comment: I've now removed the [tag:ar] tag because it messes with a routine search I do for misuses of the [tag:ar] tag and it doesn't clearly belong here.  This question appears to be abandoned; it should simply be deleted.